# if condition in BlockdeviceMapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to put "if" condition to skip the addition of the new EBS volumes in launch configuration , if there are already "available" volumes.
So logic which I am trying to achieve is that if below check variable is Null then add the new volume else skip because I am going to add "available" volume from user data.
$check = Get-EC2Volume -Filter @{ Name="status"; Values="available" }

```
BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: gp2            
            VolumeSize: '100'
        !if $check              --> not sure how to put if condition here 
        - DeviceName: /dev/sdb   
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "false"            
            VolumeSize: '50'
            VolumeType: gp2                 
        - DeviceName: /dev/sdc
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "false"            
            VolumeSize: '50'
            VolumeType: gp2
```

Comment: I don't think CloudFormation is intended to be that dynamic. Meaning, this should probably all be done at instance initialization (in user data). If you still want to control your EBS volumes "as code"; you can use the  `AWS::EC2::Volume` resource. However the association would not be as code but that's not a big deal if you ask me. Another solution would be to use Lambda custom resources, but believe me, it will be a mess to handle updates and rollbacks of dynamically allocated resources.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a condition, i.e. **AddEDrive** that checks if the parameter **EDriveSize** is specified. If it is, then it creates the BlockDeviceMapping, otherwise, do nothing.

Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/device_naming.html#available-ec2-device-names):

`/dev/sda1` is the recommended `DeviceName` for the `C:\`

`/dev/xvd[f-z]` is recommended `DeviceName` for all other additional drives.

---

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Conditions:
  AddCDrive: !Not [!Equals [!Ref CDriveSize, '']]
  AddDDrive: !Not [!Equals [!Ref DDriveSize, '']]
  AddEDrive: !Not [!Equals [!Ref EDriveSize, '']]
Parameters:
  CDriveSize: {Default: '', Type: String}
  DDriveSize: {Default: '', Type: String}
  EDriveSize: {Default: '', Type: String}
Resources:
  Instance:
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - !If
          - AddCDrive
          - DeviceName: '/dev/sda1'
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: !Ref CDriveSize
              VolumeType: gp2
          - !Ref AWS::NoValue
        - !If
          - AddDDrive
          - DeviceName: '/dev/xvdf'
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: !Ref DDriveSize
              VolumeType: gp2
          - !Ref AWS::NoValue
        - !If
          - AddEDrive
          - DeviceName: '/dev/xvdg'
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: !Ref EDriveSize
              VolumeType: gp2
          - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code how you can add a condiftion

```
            BlockDeviceMappings:
            - !If
                - IsNeedVoume
                - DeviceName: "/dev/xvdcz"
                  Ebs:
                    VolumeSize: !Ref InstanceDockerVolume
                    VolumeType: 'gp2'
                - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit on the answer? I don't know Amazon things well.